# Avoid code duplication in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, t4

I will preface this question by saying my sql is not very good :)

We are attempting to build a double buffered implementation in sql by having 2 redundant tables. At any one time 1 of the tables are active and the other inactive. The tables are accessed by a view which we toggle after reloading data. When we reload we want to perform operations on the inactive table and then toggle the active cache on completion.

We have lots of code that looks a bit like:

```
IF @activeCache = 0
   BEGIN WORK ON TABLE 1 AS IT IS INACTIVE
ELSE
   BEGIN WORK ON TABLE 0 AS IT IS INACTIVE
```

The problem is the code between the brackets is not trivial so we end up duplicating the code where the only difference is the table being operated on. We thought table parameters might help but you can't insert into them (which we need to do). My only idea now is to use T4 templates to generate the crud for us but I can't seem to get them to work in a database project.

Is there any sql constructs that can help us? We'd rather not use dynamic sql if possible.

Comment: [Related question on the DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CREATE SYNONYM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) to effectively create a permanent alias (or "synonym", if you will) for an object. You can run your logic once to decide which table to target, and then run:

```
CREATE SYNONYM WorkingTable FOR Table1
CREATE SYNONYM MainTable FOR Table2
```

Then to switch:

```
DROP SYNONYM WorkingTable
DROP SYNONYM MainTable
CREATE SYNONYM WorkingTable FOR Table2
CREATE SYNONYM MainTable FOR Table1
```

And everywhere else in your scripts, you can just reference `WorkingTable` for updates, and `MainTable` for reads.

That being said, I agree with other comments/answers that question whether this is the best way of working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two tables and switching the view, use a main table and a staging table.

When you are ready to migrate the data to the main table, you can do it in an atomic transaction like so.

```
begin try
 begin tran
 delete * from MainTable with (tablockx)
 insert MainTable
 select * from StagingTable with (tablockx)
 commit

end try
begin catch
 rollback
 raiserror('An error occurred swapping staging data', 16,16)
end catch
```

That way you always work on the staging table, so there is no difficulty identifying the correct table to use.

Depending on the data you may want to do an incremental update of the main table:

```
-- delete rows which no longer exist
delete MainTable 
from MainTable
where not exists (select 1 from StagingTable where StagingTable.primaryKey = MainTable.primaryKey)

-- Insert new rows
insert MainTable 
select * 
from StagingTable
where not exists (select 1 from MainTable where StagingTable.primaryKey = MainTable.primaryKey)


-- update rows which have changed
update MainTable 
set  
   col1 = stagingTable.col1,
   col2 = stagingTable.col2
from MainTable inner join StagingTable on  StagingTable.primaryKey = MainTable.primaryKey
where 1=2
   -- Need to compare every column, only update if one is different
   -- Both null counts as the same - compare nullity 
   OR case when MainTable.col1 is null then 0 else 1 end <> case when StagingTable.col1 is null then 0 else 1 end
   OR MainTable.col1 <> StagingTable.col1
   OR case when MainTable.col2 is null then 0 else 1 end <> case when StagingTable.col2 is null then 0 else 1 end
   OR MainTable.col2 <> StagingTable.col2
```

Comment: +1 For avoiding the 2 table idea. Chopping and changing from table to table sounds like bad news to me...What if something fails half way through your code? If you want 2 tables with the same data, you should use replication, load balancing across multiple servers or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem i see with this is it will take a long time to switch as we empty the main table and repopulate it meaning it will be down for its duration which defeats the purpose of having it 'double buffered'

Comment: @moosecode, First, have you timed it? Is it ACTUALLY a problem, or is that just a theory? Using `TABLOCKX` will speed it up enormously. Also you looked into unlogged operations which should also be faster?  Second, will the second option work? Other users may see partially updated data. This may or not be a problem depending on the data and what they are doing with it.

Comment: That `WHERE` clause is pretty horrible and can be simplified to `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT MainTable.col1, MainTable.col2 EXCEPT SELECT StagingTable.col1, StagingTable.col2)`

Comment: @Ben, no I haven't tested it I'm just imagining deleting > 1,000,000 rows and adding them back in will take a non trivial amount of time and we can't afford for the table to be unavailable. I think the switching of the view will work fine as it will be atomic and fast. At this stage I think we'll probably opt for dynamic sql as its not an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: @moosecode, consider Damien's suggestion. You can also do the updates through a view - I.e. have `table1` and `Table2`, then two views, `StagingTable` and `MainTable`. Instead of just switching `MainTable` switch them both so the point to opposite tables. Then you can just reference `WorkingTable` for updates and `MainTable` for reads.

Comment: Yes I think that is the way to go for us. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Inline Table-Valued function which takes @activeCache as a parameter. Select all data from proper table according to parameter in that function. TI'm not sure about performance.